# Visual Studio cannot keep its former layout when opened a second time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Now I am using visual studio 2010 for one solution. I reset the layout of visual studio with my preference, such as reorder Solution, Property,Toolbox pannel. But when I close the vs and open the solution again, the layout goes back to the default one of vs, not my preferred setting.

I assume, the vs will save user's layout setting automatically. But why not work for mime?

The solution is from team foundation server. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Check you don't have any `suo` files checked-in to source-control, those should always be excluded.

Comment: @Dai So you mean the layout information is in .suo file of the solution. This is an old winform application with visual studio of old version, maybe vs2005. I find there is no .suo file in the root directory of the solution, just .sln file. Do you think this is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very useful Visual Studio Plugin which allows users to change windows custom layouts. It will save your settings after configuration and load even if you close the Visual Studio and open it for the second time.

You can download from here:
http://perspectives.codeplex.com/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Do you know the reason of my problem?

Comment: @RobinSun What do you mean? According to your question, you want to reset the layout windows of Visual Studio such as solution explorer, toolbar, properties windows, etc. with your own preference? This plugin provides an easy way to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes this plugin can do what I want. But visual studio itself should have this function to keep the reset of the layout. I don't know why it cannot work for me. Maybe because this is an old version of solution which was generated in VS2005

Comment: @RobinSun I don't think it is because of VS version difference. Using the above plugin is the easiest way for you to save the layouts. But if you don't want to use the plugin, alternative solution is you can use `Tools` > 'Import And Export Settings' to save your window layouts as .vssettings file. Then, when you open the solution for the second time, use "Import And Export Settings" wizard again to restore all your previous layouts. You can read more about how to use different layout settings here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/05/the-resetsettings-switch-vstipenv0047.aspx

Comment: @RobinSun OP of this question also had the same problem like you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705161/where-is-the-visual-studio-layout-saved

Comment: But I assume that Visual Stuido should keep the layout change in memory automatically. The first time I open VS and do some change of window layout and close VS. And when I open VS the second time, it should look like what I have changed, but now for me it is just go back to the default layout. "Import And Export Settings" can help, but I need to do this every time when I open the solution, a little trouble.

Comment: @RobinSun No need to import for everytime when you start the visual studio. It will use your preferred settings once you have imported unless you make new changes to your current settings. You should read "How do settings work?" topic in this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I think I find out the reason. The solution uses Remoting. So every time I have to open 2 VS. When I change the layout VS1 and close it, actually it has save info into CurrentSetting.settings. But When I close VS2, whose layout is still default, then it rewrite CurrentSetting.setting, just let the setting info go back to the default. So when I open VS again, its layout is default. In one word, the layout is changed and saved automatically twice, which let me assume that it is never changed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RobinSun Glad to hear that you have found out your problem.